# How to make Doxygen copy "*/" without processing it

Tags: doxygen

I have a question.

I have a `mainpage` in Doxygen documentation, inside which, the end comment delimiter "*/" is in a comment, and that is where Doxygen stops generating the page, because it thinks that is the end of it. How can I make Doxygen copy it without processing it?

It looks something like this:

```
/**
@mainpage
The end comment delimiter in Doxygen is */
... bla bla bla...
**/
```

Here I should mention that I have already tried `@code` and `@verbatim`, but those are making code blocks, which I do not desire.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also a bit of a hack, but for HTML and LaTeX output you could use

```
/**
@mainpage
The end comment delimiter in Doxygen is \endcomment
... bla bla bla...
**/
```

Along with the following alias definition in the config file:

```
ALIASES = endcomment="\htmlonly&#42;/\endhtmlonly\latexonly$\ast$/\endlatexonly"
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there also something for PDF and RTF?

Comment: PDF is generated from latex, so that will work with the above solution. For RTF there is still an issue with \rtfonly..\endrtfonly in doxygen which I need to fix (target release 1.8.1). Then you could add \rtfonly\'2a/\endrtfonly to the alias definition to make it work for RTF as well.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work (for C# at least):

```
/**
@mainpage
The end comment delimiter in Doxygen is
**/
/// */ \n
/**
... bla bla bla...
**/
```

The `///` continues on the previous comment, but as it's not started with a `/**`, the `*/` is not taken to be the end of that comment. The `\n` is to put the `... bla bla bla...` on a new line.

## EDIT

This works for a doxygen comment for a construct within the program (like a class or enum), but not in the `@mainpage` section.

## SECOND EDIT

Using only single-line comments, and setting the `MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF` flag now seems to work with the `mainpage` section

```
/// @mainpage
/// The end comment delimiter in Doxygen is */
/// ... bla bla bla...
```

This obviously means that you'll need to use the `///` comment style, at least for the main page section, but that seems like the only option (unless `* /` is a viable option :P)

Comment: It is not working with my C++ stuff :(
When I do `\f$ */ \f$`, then it works if you have LaTeX installed, but what Doxygen does is, it generates an equation using LaTeX, makes a bitmap image out of it, and embeds it into the HTML page (or PDF, depending on what you want as output). As long as you do not want to generate RTF (which I do not), it works. But I am still curious how this could be done with pure text only.

Comment: Ah, apologies - I tried it with a class comment I already had and that was ok, but it seems with the `@mainpage` it doesn't work the same way.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another suggestion for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! This would be suitable if I had a very tiny mainpage. But since the mainpage has hundreds of lines, this can get really tedious, unless I write a script to put `///` in front of every line. I am surprised Doxygen does not have any special command that would just print the content without processing it.

Comment: In all honesty, I'm quite surprised too - an inlineverbatim command seems like a sensible thing to have. A regex should be able to add a `///` to the start of every line (not too hot on regex, though, so I'm not exactly sure how to do it - something about anchors...)